# Android Async not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an AsyncTask. I want to pair with a bluetooth device, and only after pairing it should go to next activity. My code is

```
public class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    public BluetoothDevice d;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        //pairDevice(d);
        return null;
    }
    public void onPreExecute()
    {
        pairDevice(d);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        CharSequence text = "Pairing";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        startActivity(new Intent(NewDeviceActivity.this,DevicesActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
 void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {

        Method m = device.getClass()
                .getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

The onPostExecute function gets executed even before pairDevice function has finished. Please help

Comment: move your `pairDevice` method call inside `doInBackground` method and it should work. And also initialize your `BluetoothDevice` reference. Cause currently you have a `refrence` of  `BluetoothDevice` not an Object of `BluetoothDevice`

Answer (score 0):

The `onPostExecute()` method gets triggered after the tasks in `doInBackground()` have been completed. In your example you are not executing any tasks in `doInBackground()`, resulting in `onPostExecute()` to be called immediately. Move your method `pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device)` into the `doInBackground()` method and it should work.

Comment: the pairDevice opens another thread, and it doesnt wait for the other thread to finish

Answer (score 0):

Background Long operations should be done only in `doInBackground` method. This is the actual flow.

```
 @Override
 public void onPreExecute()
    {
       // this executes before Background operation starts
       // here you can start showing ProgressBar to let the users know that it's still doing the work and you can dismiss in onPostExecute
    }

 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        // here you should do the long operation
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
      // here you can update the UI or move to other activity after long task has been done
     }
```

The problem is, you are trying to run Background operation in `onPreExecute`.

```
 public void onPreExecute()
 {
        pairDevice(d);
 }
```

Just move the `pairDevice(d)` method to `doInBackground` method which is not correct.

Comment: the pairDevice opens another thread, and it doesnt wait for the other thread to finish